# How to load HTML Elements after JavaScript Function?

Tags: javascript, html

I started learning JavaScript recently, and was practicing with prompt boxes, and found [SweetAlert](http://t4t5.github.io/sweetalert/). Used it to display a small dialog box with a placeholder in it. It turned out well.

But, the HTML Elements I want to load, loads before the dialog box appear. I mean, those elements are visible in the background. I want them to load only after the Dialog Box event is over. Here's my **[Code at JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/anirudhkarthik/jSQrj/158/)**

```
window.onload = function() {

  swal({
    title: "An input!",
    text: "Write something interesting:",
    type: "input",
    showCancelButton: true,
    closeOnConfirm: false,
    animation: "slide-from-top",
    inputPlaceholder: "Write something"
  }, function(inputValue) {
    if (inputValue === false) return false;
    if (inputValue === "") {
      swal.showInputError("You need to write something!");
      return false
    }
    swal.close();
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = inputValue;
  });

}
```

I want the HTML text to be loaded after the dialog box event is done. Hope you get it. 
I've just started to learn, so a noob-friendly answer would be appreciated. Thanks :)

Comment: You don't want to deliberately extend the "loading" time of your content - just [hide it until you are ready to show it](http://jsfiddle.net/jSQrj/166/).

Comment: Thank a ton, Emissar. Will try this too!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put the items you want to hide in a separate div, and then you can just hide and show that div. see how it works in [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ahmetcetin/jSQrj/165/)

```
window.onload = function() {
    document.getElementById("willbehidden").style.display = "none";

  swal({
    title: "An input!",
    text: "Write something interesting:",
    type: "input",
    showCancelButton: true,
    closeOnConfirm: false,
    animation: "slide-from-top",
    inputPlaceholder: "Write something"
  }, function(inputValue) {
    if (inputValue === false) return false;
    if (inputValue === "") {
      swal.showInputError("You need to write something!");
      return false
    }
    swal.close();
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = inputValue;
      document.getElementById("willbehidden").style.display = "block";
  });

}
```

Comment: I wish I could upvote the answer, I don't have the reputation to do it. Thanks a lot :D

Comment: np, it's nice feeling to be able to help someone!